# Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager Not opening menu

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Recently uninstalled my old local cluster and reinstalled the new one (using Platform installer)

Every since then the manager doesnt respond to right clicks. (Normally a right click opens up a small menu with start, stop, reset etc). Sometimes it will open the window but it will be 30+ minutes later.

I know everything in the background is working as I'm able to still publish to my local 1 node but I cant use the GUI.

What I've tried:

1. Uninstall + reinstall
2. Killing the program via task manager and re opening

Question 1- How do I fix this so I can use the GUI?
Question 2- Where can I find the terminal commands to manage the cluster if the GUI doesnt work?

Comment: I've been having this exact same issue, and it persists even after uninstalling and installing a new version of the runtime and SDK.